# Firebase Storage returning nil for url

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

The following code is not working for me. I have `/places/` folder in storage, and inside that I have images. This is returning nil for url -

```
let storage = Storage.storage()
let storageRef = storage.reference()
let placesRef = storageRef.child("places/\(image).jpg")

placesRef.downloadURL { url, error in
    if let error = error {
    // Handle any errors
    print("Failed to download url:", error)
    return
    } else {
    // Get the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'

        self.placeURL = url!
        image = "\(url!)"
    }
}
```

Error in console: `Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL"...`
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that error is coming from the code you show here? I suspect it's coming from something else.

Answer (score 1):

You are right Doug, I simple never updated @Published var in this code.... one simple if before

```
image = "\(url!)"
```

and set new value in @Published var array resolved my problem. Always update @Published one in SwiftUI! :)